# Generating PDB file from electron density without force field minimization

Tags: crystal-structure, software, molecular-mechanics

Is there a step-by-step tutorial on how to generate a PDB file from an electron density file (`*.ccp4`)?

For my current project, I am trying to take some statistics of some PDB files. However, I do not think that the empirical energy function (MM) implemented in x-plorer could accurately reproduce experimental or QM data. As a result, I would like to use x-plorer to generate the raw PDB file myself (without minimization), but since I have never done this before, I was wondering if somebody could provide me some guidance on how this could be done.

Comment: Is it a PDB (Protein Data Bank) file with macromolecular structure?

Comment: @marcin, yes it is

Comment: "the raw PDB file (without minimization)" - this is not clear to me

Comment: all PDB structures undergo force field minimization after the x-ray diffraction data is obtained. This is done for refinement purposes. However, force fields are far from perfect, and I was interested in the structures from the raw diffraction data.

Comment: No, they usually don't. Perhaps you think about restraints that are used during the refinement.

Comment: @marcin I don't agree. Crystal structure refinement uses a priori information, which is derived from the CHARMM force field within the XPLORER program. The restraints which you talk about are the crystal structure diffraction data. The refinement is a combination of the two processes, force field and diffraction data.

Comment: Saying that restraints are the diffraction data makes no sense. Restraints are the a priori information.You may google "Engh and Huber refinement restraints" to read about the most popular restraints. I'm not familiar x-plorer. The vast majority of structures in the PDB is refined with Phenix.refine, Refmac or Buster.

Comment: @marcin It looks like my terminology was swapped. It seems like restraints are the force field data. In any case, it is well known that x-ray crystal structures undergo MM minimization (just look at the paper you suggested I google), so there is no point arguing about this.

Answer (score 1):

The process of making structural models of macromolecules (the content of PDB files) is called model building, rather than generating, because it normally involves tedious manual building of the model in a graphical program such as Coot. A few programs can do automatic model building, but then the structure needs to be finished manually. Maybe this will change in the future.
All these programs have rather steep learning curve, so it's probably not what you are looking for.

The next problem is that you plan to start from an electron density map.
Assuming that the experimental method was crystallography, not Cryo-EM, the electron density map is derived from both reflection data and the model (and at the same time the model is built into the map, iteratively). So for the purpose of re-building or validation people generally use reflection data, not the map.